# How to get LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE from android device

Tags: android, android-camera2, autofocus

From android camera api2, we are able to set LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE (from 0 to 10). My question is how to get the LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE? For example, after auto focusing, I want to know the current focus distance. Which function I should call? Thanks.

Comment: I'm also interested in this question. Please, let us know if you find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback and supply it to your CaptureRequest.Builder.

```
mPreviewSession.capture(mPreviewBuilder.build(), captureCallbackHandler, mBackgroundHandler);
```

Then override the onCaptureCompleted method within the CaptureCallback and you should be able to read the LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE from the TotalCaptureResult.

```
private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallbackHandler = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
        super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
        float focusDistance = result.get(CaptureResult.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE);
    }
}
```

I am able to read from this after auto focusing on my nexus5 but not on the s8. Perhaps samsung has limited this capability to promote usage of their own camera sdk.